# Copying large file does not work in flutter

Tags: file, flutter, copy, assets, large-data

I try to use a 665 MB size Database file (SQLite file) for my flutter app.
(the file is needed since it provides offline-data for a public transportation App. And therefore I cannot make it smaller).

So far, when using any SQLite file in Flutter, I normally copy it in code.
The original location of the file is `./assets/db_file.db`.
The destination location of the file is `DocumentsDirectory`.

Now I have the problem that the file-copy does not work for my 665 MB large DB-file.

Here is my code that fails to copy due to the large size of the file.

(for smaller files, this code works well)...:

(also, in the Simulator the code works well, no matter the large file-size. The problem only occurs on an actual iPhone)...

```
Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
var dbPath = join(directory.path, "destinationFile.db");
if (FileSystemEntity.typeSync(dbPath) == FileSystemEntityType.notFound) {
  ByteData data = await rootBundle.load("assets/largeFile.db");
  List<int> bytes =
      data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
  await File(dbPath).writeAsBytes(bytes);
}
```

For my 665 MB file the above code crashes - without error message :/

The line of code it crashes is the following:

```
ByteData data = await rootBundle.load("assets/largeFile.db");
```

Questions:

- is there any way to improve my above code for very large files so that no crash ocurrs ??
- is there any way to provide the db-file inside the documents-folder in the first place (as part of the bundle, i.e. so that no copying is needed) ??
- how should I proceed with such a large file anyway ??

Comment: I guess it's because it's because you run out of memory. There should be a `load` method that returns a `Stream` that you can pipe to `File(dbPath)` so that chunks of data are read-written-disposed until the complete file is copied instead of loading the whole file into memory and then writing it back to disk. Unfortunately AssetBundle doesn't seem to provide such a method.

Comment: Yes, this is very unfortunate ! (thank you anyway for your answer) ! My iPhone5S certainly does not provide enough memory for the `root.load` method provided by dart.

Comment: I'd implement the file copy in Java/ObjectC and just invoke it from Flutter like explained in https://flutter.io/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages

Comment: ah - that is an idea. I did not know you can invoke Java/ObjC code in Flutter. Thanks for the hint, ...I'll give it a try !

Comment: Sure, there are tons of plugins that do that if you need examples. https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages and many of https://pub.dartlang.org/flutter

Comment: thank you very much, Günter, for the links. I am very well learning flutter :) One more question: What would the file path be of the ./asset-folder inside the plugin-worlds (i.e. iOS-plugin and Android-plugin) ? Do you know by chance ?